# What formats does ActionView::Digestor.new accept for name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, cache-digests

I'm poking around in the console to figure out how cache digest dependencies are calculated. This works for the app/views/posts/show.html.haml template:

```
ActionView::Digestor.new(name: "posts/show", finder: finder).digest
# => Cache digest for app/views/posts/show.html.haml: 42bf3496bacfcf84492d8c05d81305fe
```

Neither of these work for the app/views/posts/_post.html.haml template:

```
ActionView::Digestor.new(name: "posts/_post", finder: finder).digest
# =>  Couldn't find template for digesting: posts/_post
ActionView::Digestor.new(name: "posts/post", finder: finder).digest
# =>  Couldn't find template for digesting: posts/post
```

(for both, `finder = ApplicationController.new.lookup_context`)

How can ActionView be told to look for this partial?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/digestor.rb) I would expect that this works:

```
ActionView::Digestor.digest(
  name:   'posts/_post', 
  finder:  finder,
  partial: true
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When testing this I encountered this issue, maybe you have some thoughts: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18595